# Men & Mice unable to connect to AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, ipam

I have a Men & Mice (8.2.2) installation managing DNS (bind) on our internal networks. We use Route53 for public DNS. M&M 8.2 added better cloud integration, so I am attempting to connect the two. No dice. The M&M docs are completely unhelpful on the subject.

Regardless of the credentials I use when attempting to configure an AWS service account from the M&M console, the error message is the same - a timeout trying to establish connection "Unable to connect to endpoint."

The M&M central server can see AWS just fine - I even installed the AWS cli tools on the host and can perform Route53 actions with the IAM credentials I want to eventually use. Rudimentary packet sniffing on the server does show some encrypted traffic going out to AWS when I try to configure things (but I've not tried to go any deeper than that).

Does anyone have experience with M&M's cloud service integration? Is there some super obvious first step that I need to take first, or some better way to debug this process?

Comment: What endpoint is it trying to connect to? It doesn't sound like a standard security group / NACL problem as I assume it's connecting to an AWS service endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the inconvenience.

This will be fixed in next minor version of Men & Mice and I am told the documentation will be improved over the weekend.

The application is looking for a file that is missing on some supported Linux distributions. You can work around this issue on Ubuntu by creating a symlink like this:

```
mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs/
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Hope this helps. You are welcome to contact support@menandmice.com if you need more assistance.

Comment: Thank you - this appears to have resolved the initial issue. Now I am getting  authorization errors and just have to figure out what IAM permission it actually expects :)